# integrating react native app in my kmm project

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, kotlin-multiplatform

i read multiple articles talking about being able to somehow embed a react native application into a ios / android native application. However it is always the other way around, which means that it's describing how to have native modules inside the react native application. In this case i wanted to embed Rocket.Chat into my kotlin multiplatform mobile project which i have been building for quite some time now but if i understand it correctly, i would have to make my project part of the rocket.chat application. Is there an option / instruction where i could not do it this way and simply embed the chat into my project?

i was expecting to embed rocket.chat, which is a react native mobile application, into my KMM project to use it as a chat. However i find no option to call / start rocket.chat (which can also be whitelabeled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to embed a React Native app into a native iOS or Android app, but it is not a straightforward process. One approach would be to use a "WebView" component in your native app, which allows you to load and display web content within your app.

You can use the WebView as a container for your Rocket.Chat React Native app. This way, you can load the Rocket.Chat app in the WebView, and it will appear as if it's part of your native app.

You may also use the react-native-webview package to load the Rocket.Chat app in the WebView.

Keep in mind that this approach may have some limitations, such as the Rocket.Chat app not having full access to the native features of the device, and the performance may not be optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! However that creates another question for me. how would i call the react native app from the webview? all the documentation i saw only explained the case for calling a website using an url but not a react native mobile app.

Comment: yw, u can use deep links, with this feature u can call react native app when click on a link